# Combining an `<iron-list>` with a `<paper-scroll-header-panel>`

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

The `<iron-list>` ([docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list)) requires a fixed height, yet on the other hand `<paper-scroll-header-panel>` ([docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-scroll-header-panel), [demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-scroll-header-panel?view=demo:demo/index.html)) expects the `<div>` to have more height than is available, thus allowing you to collapse the header whilst scrolling. How can one combine these two elements in such a way that the iron list recalculates properly (manually resize it and trigger the resize event? :S ) whilst the header becomes smaller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this layout below. As long as the `iron-list`'s parent - `paper-scroll-header-panel` has a `fit` selector, it should just work without doing anything extra.

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel class="fit" condenses keep-condensed-header>
  <paper-toolbar class="tall">
  </paper-toolbar>
  <iron-list items="[[data]]">
```

This is because -

> iron-list must ether be explicitly sized, or delegate scrolling to an
>   explicitly sized parent. By "explicitly sized", we mean it either has
>   an explicit CSS height property set via a class or inline style, or
>   else is sized by other layout means (e.g. the flex or fit classes).

You can read this from the [official document](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list) and also check out this [live demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list?view=demo:demo/index.html) with these two working together.

Comment: How can I have stared at that demo a million times just 2 days ago and not realized it was already combing them... and what in the world is going wrong with my constructions then :S Ach ach, but thanks! Will probably accept tomorrow after having a fresh look at it.